# C#: Увеличить два числа сохраняя их пропорции чтобы их сумма была не больше другого числа

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Допустим, есть два числа:

int x1 = 1920

int y1 = 1080

Нужно максимально их увеличить, но так, чтобы при этом сохранялось их соотношение (в данном случае 16:9), а так же их сумма не должна быть больше определённого числа (допустим, это 10000).

На выходе мы должны получить x2 и y2.